# What's the linux enquivalent of: ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

So the example code from my class looks like this:

```
import ctypes

attribute = 0x02

return = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW ('filename.txt', attribute)
```

Running this gets me the following output:

```
return = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW('filename.txt', attribute)
AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll'
```

How do i get the same effect in Linux? I'm running distro Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Attribute `0x02` is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`.

Comment: What does file attribute 2 mean in Windows?

Comment: You don't. There is no such thing in Linux.

Comment: Linux doesn't have hidden files. By convention, filenames beginning with `.` are hidden -- `ls` and GUI file managers don't show them by default, and wildcards don't match them unless the wildcard begins with `.`.

Comment: And more generally, Linux files don't have a list of boolean attributes that can be set. The only common attributes are permission modes, owner, and group.